# Dynamic importing of json file is not refreshing

Tags: dynamic, import, json-format

Running

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Import["foo.json"], UpdateInterval->1]]
```

or

```
json := Import["foo.json"]
```

then

```
Dynamic[Refresh[json, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

do not update as expected!

I can evaluate json manually and get the current json in the file, but if I change the contents of the file, the output of `Dynamic` remains static.

Is there a way to achieve this sort of thing?

Comment: Try `Dynamic[Refresh[json, TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clock.html). The following will import `foo.json` every 5 seconds.

```
With[{update = 5},
  Dynamic[{foo = Import["~/Desktop/foo.json"], 
           Clock[{1, update, update}, update]}]]
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks!

Comment: But why is UpdateInterval not working?

Comment: The update interval of 5 sec. works as expected in the code I posted in this answer, so I don't understand what you asking?